# Get new incoming emails and write their flat file link to a file

Tags: c#, outlook, exchange-server

I want to get all incoming mails for  a certain mailbox and write their Subject , date and flat file link (e.g /-FlatUrlSpace-/5a194b8c1256794581cb898e6b93c34f-112ca9b4/68fcbe48ba7a604086372757c4cea3de-44e6af ) to a file.

How would i go about doing this codewise, i've never worked with the outlook object and know very little about exchange so i'm hoping for some help.

Is there an event for new incoming mails?

Is there a property where i can get the flaturlspace, cause i can't see anything related to it

thx in advance

Comment: Which Exchange version are you working with? Both, Exchange 2003 and 2007 provide the FlatUrlSpace scheme. But with Exchange 2007 there are far better options available to solve your task.

Comment: Are you working the Outlook object model or are your working directly agains the Exchange Server? Cause Flaturlspace is kind of WebDAV specific. In Outlook you would use the EntryId of an item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way that I've done this in the past is by using WEBDAV. I seem to recall you can request flaturlspace.

Check out [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314181).